# Corona sdk display multi line notification

Tags: android, lua, push-notification, notifications, coronasdk

I have some notifications in Corona. The problem is, the text is too big, and I would need to show bigger (multi line) notifications, like the Gmail app, for example. Here is what the notifications look like now:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
local notificationOptions =
{
  alert = text,
  badge = 2,
  sound = "alarm.caf",
  custom = { foo = "bar" }
}

 local notification = notifications.scheduleNotification( nextScheduleTime +  ( day + math.floor(day/7)) * 24 * 60 * 60, notificationOptions )
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: have you tried adding a newline character `\n` and see what happens?

Comment: yes, nothing happens, unfortunately.

Comment: try using \n in your text that possibly creates a new line

Answer (score -1):

The notifications by default are not provide multilines.

To use several lines, you have to `NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()` in Java ([sample](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16266684/1979882)) or use your custom or native custom View ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16168704/1979882)).

Unfortunately, I've not found how you can touch the default view in order to override

Manual:
https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/events/appNotification/index.html#TOC

and here:
https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/plugin/notifications/scheduleNotification.html

in the second link you can see that only this properties are used:

> alert (optional) String. The notification message to be displayed to
>   the user. If the application is not currently running, a system alert
>   will display this message. badge (optional) Number. The badge number
>   to be displayed on the application icon when the scheduled
>   notification triggers. This replaces the last badge number that was
>   applied. Set to 0 to omit the badge number. This option is not
>   supported on Android. sound (optional) String. Name of the sound file
>   in the system.ResourceDirectory to be played when the scheduled
>   notification triggers. This sound is only played if the app is not
>   currently in the foreground. On iOS, there are limitations on the
>   kinds of sound that can be played (consult Apple's documentation for
>   more details). custom (optional) Table. A table that will be delivered
>   with the notification event. This allows you to pass custom
>   information with the notification.

In conclusion, there is no proper way to do it nowadays.